# Is a US reentry permit useful for more than 1 entry into the US?

Tags: usa, resident-permit, french-citizens

Is a US reentry permit useful for more than 1 entry into the US? E.g., if a US lawful permanent resident and French citizen applies for reentry permit (via [Form I-131, Application for Travel Document](https://www.uscis.gov/i-131) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200823021419/https://www.uscis.gov/i-131))) and gets it, then stays outside the US for 2 months, comes back to the US for 1 month, stays outside the US for 5 months, comes back to the US for 1 month, and stays outside the US for 13 months, is the US reentry permit still valid for the second and third entries to the US?

https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/guides/B5en.pdf ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200806223451/https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/guides/B5en.pdf)) states:

> A reentry permit establishes that you did not intend to abandon
> status, and **it allows you to apply for admission to the United States
> after traveling abroad for up to 2 years without having to obtain
> a returning resident visa**. Reentry permits are normally valid for 2
> years from the date of issuance.

but I don't know whether the reentry permit for more than one stay outside the US.

Comment: I think it's a one-off because the form doesn't let you indicate multiple trips like the advance parole section does. It also assumes you're out of the country, also unlike the advanced parole section. I'm not sure though, so not an answer.

Comment: on the other hand, [this document](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/guides/B5en.pdf) says you must apply for a re-entry permit before leaving the US and says it can even be used like a passport for some countries, so??